# Find an orthonormal basis for W and $W ^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V=\mathbb{P}^{2}$ with the inner product $<p(x),q(x)>=2p(-1)q(-1)+3p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)$

Let $W=Span${$x,x^{2}$} Find the orthonormal basis for W using Gramm-Schmidt.

Then express the polynomial $p(x)=x^{2}-2x+3$ as the sum $p(x)=w_{1}(x)+w_{2}(x)$ where $w_{1}(x)\in W$ and $w_{2}(x)\in W ^{\perp}$. Using this find a basis for $W ^{\perp}$.

so far I have found the orthonormal basis for W which is $S=\left \{\frac{1}{3}x,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}x^{2}-x  \right \}$

now for the next part I am unsure of what part is $w_{1}(x)$ and $w_{2}(x)$ in addition I don't know how I will get the 3 in $p(x)$ since there is no number without x attached in my basis. What I am thinking is that $w_{2}(x)$ itself must be 1 or something so that i can get 3 so my answer would be something like $x^{2}-2x+3=a(x)+b(x^{2}-x)+c(1)$ where $a=-1, b=1, c=3$

Comment: Check the basis of $V$.

Comment: Do you mean the standard basis for $\mathbb{P}^{2}$, which would be $V=Span${$1,x,x^{2}$}?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: okay, so since $W=Span${$x,x^{2}$} would that mean $w_{2}(x)$ ={$x,x^{2}$} and $w_{1}(x)$ = {1}? if thats the case that means the final part is just in the wrong order right?

Comment: I told you this just I want you to know what spans $W^{T}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_1, b_2$ be the orthonormal basis for $W$. If $p=w_1+w_2$, with $w_1 \in W$ and $w_2 \in W^\bot$, then you can compute $w_1$ easily since $\langle b_k, p \rangle = \langle b_k, w_1 \rangle$. That is, $w_1 = \sum_{k=1}^2 \langle b_k, p \rangle b_k$.

Then $w_2 = p-w_1$.
Since $w_2 \neq 0$, and $\dim W^\bot = 3 - \dim W = 1$, we see that $W^\bot = \operatorname{sp} \{ w_2 \}$. All that remains is to normalize $w_2$ to get
$b_3 = {1 \over \sqrt{\langle w_2, w_2 \rangle}} w_2$.